# Generating 8-bit unique random number

Tags: c, algorithm, random, data-structures

Is there any better way to generate 8-bit **unique** and **random** number in constant time ?

Below implementation returns 8-bit unique random number, but complexity is O(n=256) as it has to loop through the `is_generated`[] array till it generates one which has not been previously generated. Also it needs extra space for `is_generated`.

```
uint8_t
random_octate(void)
{   
    static bool     is_generated[256] = {false};
    uint32_t        num = rand()%256;

    while(is_generated[num])
    {
        num = rand() % 256;
    }

    is_generated[num] = true;
    return num;
}
```

Comment: Pre-shuffle values [0..255] with Fisher-Yates is a fine answer as already given. I'll add that your question is broken.  256 numbers guaranteed not to have repeats are _not_ random.  They are a random permutation of [0..255], which is exactly what Fished-Yates produces.

Answer (score 6):

Generate (0..255), then shuffle. Then give out the elements one by one. Shuffling is O(n), done once for 256 values, so cost per element is O(1); and obviously returning a single element is also O(1).

Comment: Since n cannot be greater than 256, O(n) *is* O(1). Aside from that technicality, you can shuffle incrementally using F-Y, so you only have to do one swap to produce the next random element. Of course, you do have to initialize the reservoir to {0..255} but that can be done with static initialization (which is another technicality)

Answer (score 3):

Since the data set is so limited there shouldn't be problem in allocating 256 values, shuffle them and extract them in order, [something like](http://ideone.com/5c7F4j):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
static uint8_t data[256];
static int index;

void init_random()
{
  srand(NULL);

  index = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    data[i] = i;

  // bad choice, use fisher-yates for example
  for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
  {
    int i1 = rand()%256, i2 = rand()%256;
    uint8_t t = data[i1];
    data[i1] = data[i2];
    data[i2] = t;
  }
}

uint8_t extract()
{
  return data[index++];
}


int main(void)
{
  init_random();
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    printf("%d\n", extract());
}
```

Comment: What is the benefit of keeping loop size 10000, instead 256. Ultimately you are shuffling elements in array data?

Comment: First of all I specified that it's a bad choice and a proper algorithm (like Fisher-Yates) should be used. It's just a trivial implementation to give the idea to the OP, the amount of shuffles is larger than the data set size just to have more probability to shuffle each element at least once.